How to handle big json data in react js?
I am trying to develop a list of products to display in react js.
I am using local data.json file for now but will fetch from an API in future.
my data.json sample is
{
"Result": "OK",
"Code": 200,
"famproduct": [
  {
    "Prd_Code": "701012583",
    "Descr": "B FIT ADULT PANTS L10 ",
    "Company_Name": "ANEV",
    "Packing": "",
    "Sr_No": 1,
    "Sale_Rate": 450.1488,
    "Max_Rate": 605,
    "Batch_No": "",
    "Expiry": "  -",
    "Gst_Perc": 12,
    "P_Code": "AYAN0027"
  },..and other lots of data..,
  {
    "Prd_Code": "701012584",
    "Descr": "B FIT ADULT PANTS XL10 ",
    "Company_Name": "ANEV",
    "Packing": "",
    "Sr_No": 1,
    "Sale_Rate": 491.0714,
    "Max_Rate": 660,
    "Batch_No": "",
    "Expiry": "  -",
    "Gst_Perc": 12,
    "P_Code": "AYAN0027"
  }
 ],
"Message": "List Record"
}

I am trying to display this json data in a list and added buttons in every list item.
ISSUE
Issue is whenever I click a listitem button, it shows very slow response.
What I did
I tried to reduce json data and it worked properly. So I guess there is issue with this big json data.
What should I do so my interaction with buttons don't lag.? 
UPDATE 
here i am showing the issue i am facing
ISSUE CLICK HERE
some part of my code shown below
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  Container,
  Typography,
  List,
  ListItem,
  Paper,
  Button,
  IconButton,
  TextField,
} from "@mui/material";
import { Add } from "@mui/icons-material";
import DeleteIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Delete";
import AddShoppingCartIcon from "@mui/icons-material/AddShoppingCart";
import mydata from "../data.json";

import "./style.css";

interface Product {
  Descr: string;
  Prd_Code: string;
  Company_Name: string;
  Gst_Perc: number;
  Max_Rate: number;
  Sale_Rate: number;
  Batch_No?: string;
  Expiry?: string;
}

const ProductList: React.FC = () => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState<Product[]>(mydata.famproduct || []);
  const [qty, setQty] = useState<{ [key: string]: number }>({});
  const [expandedProduct, setExpandedProduct] = useState<string | null>(null);

  const handleAddToQty = (Prd_Code: string) => {
    setQty((prevQty) => ({
      ...prevQty,
      [Prd_Code]: (prevQty[Prd_Code] || 0) + 1,
    }));
  };

  const handleIncreaseQuantity = (Prd_Code: string) => {
    setQty((prevQty) => ({
      ...prevQty,
      [Prd_Code]: prevQty[Prd_Code] + 1,
    }));
  };

  const handleDecreaseQuantity = (Prd_Code: string) => {
    setQty((prevQty) => {
      const newQuantity = (prevQty[Prd_Code] || 0) - 1;
      if (newQuantity > 0) {
        return {
          ...prevQty,
          [Prd_Code]: newQuantity,
        };
      } else {
        const { [Prd_Code]: _, ...rest } = prevQty;
        return rest;
      }
    });
  };

  const handleQuantityChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>, Prd_Code: string) => {
    const value = parseInt(event.target.value, 10);
    if (value > 0) {
      setQty((prevQty) => ({
        ...prevQty,
        [Prd_Code]: value,
      }));
    }
  };

  const toggleDetails = (Prd_Code: string) => {
    setExpandedProduct((prev) => (prev === Prd_Code ? null : Prd_Code));
  };

  const calculateTotalPrice = () => {
    return products.reduce((total, product) => {
      const quantity = qty[product.Prd_Code] || 0;
      const saleRate = product.Sale_Rate || 0;
      const gstp = product.Gst_Perc || 0;
      return total + (saleRate * quantity + (saleRate * quantity) * gstp / 100);
    }, 0);
  };

  return (
    <Container>
      <Paper style={{ padding: 20 }}>
        <Typography variant="h4" align="center" gutterBottom>
          Product Descriptions
        </Typography>
        <List>
          {products.map((product, index) => (
            <ListItem key={index}>
              <Typography
                variant="body1"
                style={{
                  width: "100%",
                  backgroundColor: "#f9f9f9",
                  borderRadius: "10px",
                  padding: "10px",
                }}
              >
                <div
                  style={{
                    display: "flex",
                    justifyContent: "space-between",
                    alignItems: "center",
                  }}
                >
                  <div style={{ lineHeight: "0.3" }}>
                    <p className="code">{product.Prd_Code}</p>
                    <p className="descr">{product.Descr}</p>
                  </div>
                  <div style={{ paddingRight: "5px" }}>
                    {qty[product.Prd_Code] ? (
                      <div style={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "center" }}>
                        <IconButton
                          size="small"
                          onClick={() =>
                            handleDecreaseQuantity(product.Prd_Code)
                          }
                        >
                          <DeleteIcon fontSize="inherit" />
                        </IconButton>
                        <TextField
                          type="number"
                          value={qty[product.Prd_Code] || 0} // Display quantity or 0 if undefined
                          onChange={(event: any) => handleQuantityChange(event, product.Prd_Code)}
                          inputProps={{ min: 1 }}
                          style={{ width: "70px", margin: "0 10px" }}
                          InputProps={{
                            style: {
                              height: "30px", // Adjust the height if needed
                              // padding: "0 5px",
                              fontSize: "14px", // Set the font size for the input value
                              textAlign: "center", // Center the text inside the input
                            },
                          }}
                          InputLabelProps={{
                            style: {
                              fontSize: "0.9rem",
                            },
                          }}
                        />

                        <IconButton
                          size="small"
                          onClick={() =>
                            handleIncreaseQuantity(product.Prd_Code)
                          }
                        >
                          <Add fontSize="inherit" />
                        </IconButton>
                      </div>
                    ) : (
                      <Button
                        variant="contained"
                        color="primary"
                        style={{ background: "#2FD000", height: "30px" }}
                        onClick={() => handleAddToQty(product.Prd_Code)}
                      >
                        <AddShoppingCartIcon />
                        Add
                      </Button>
                    )}
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div
                  style={{
                    display: "flex",
                    justifyContent: "space-between",
                    marginTop: "10px",
                  }}
                >
                  
                  <Button
                    variant="contained"
                    size="small"
                    color="info"
                    onClick={() => toggleDetails(product.Prd_Code)}
                  >
                    {expandedProduct === product.Prd_Code
                      ? "Hide Details"
                      : "Show Details"}
                  </Button>
                  {qty[product.Prd_Code] && (
                    <Typography
                      variant="body2"
                      style={{ color: "green" }}
                    >
                      PRODUCT NET VALUE:{" "}
                      {(qty[product.Prd_Code] * product.Sale_Rate + (qty[product.Prd_Code] * product.Sale_Rate) * product.Gst_Perc / 100).toFixed(2)}{" "}
                      <span>&#8377;</span>
                    </Typography>
                  )}
                </div>
                {expandedProduct === product.Prd_Code && (
                  <div>
                    <table
                      border={1}
                      width={"100%"}
                      style={{ marginTop: "10px" }}
                    >
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td className="heading">Company Name</td>
                          <td className="table_value">
                            {product.Company_Name}
                          </td>
                          <td className="heading">GST %</td>
                          <td className="table_value">
                            {product.Gst_Perc}
                            <span>&#x25;</span>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td className="heading">MRP</td>
                          <td className="table_value">
                            <span>&#8377;</span>
                            {product.Max_Rate}
                          </td>
                          <td className="heading">Sale Price</td>
                          <td className="table_value">
                            <span>&#8377;</span>
                            {product.Sale_Rate}
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                        {product.Batch_No && (
                          <tr>
                            <td className="heading">Batch No</td>
                            <td className="table_value">{product.Batch_No}</td>
                          </tr>
                        )}
                        {product.Expiry && product.Expiry.trim() !== "-" && (
                          <tr>
                            <td className="heading">Expiry</td>
                            <td className="table_value">{product.Expiry}</td>
                          </tr>
                        )}
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                )}
              </Typography>
            </ListItem>
          ))}
        </List>
        <Typography
          variant="h6"
          style={{ marginTop: "20px", textAlign: "right", color: "blue" }}
        >
          Total Qty Price: <span>&#8377;</span>
          {calculateTotalPrice().toFixed(2)}
        </Typography>
      </Paper>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default ProductList;


Thanks for helping.

The lag in your React component buttons may be due to the large amount of data being processed and rendered. Here are some options:

Use React's memo to avoid unnecessary re-renders
Use "key" prop effectively (underrated)
Also you could find a way to render only the visual content (like lazy loading)

